# OS X 10.7 + Python 3.3 + numpy + matplotlib

Tags: macos, numpy, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have been trying to get Matplotlib running in 3.3 with no luck.

I downloaded the latest github repos for [matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib), which depends on [numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy).

For numpy I did 'python3 setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95' then 'python3 setup.py install'.  I think I installed gfortran a while ago, not sure if it comes w/ xcode.

I built installed matplotlib the same way, except not specifying a compiler - just 'python3 setup.py build'

Numpy only has a handfull of errors on unit testing, whereas matplotlib is one giant fail.

numpy unit tests: http://pastebin.com/5XF0qAe5
matplotlib unit tests: http://pastebin.com/DHGeFSGz

I don't know what to try next!  I would much rather learn how to build it myself than download a binary.

Total noob question: do I need to install this from any particular directory?  I just unzipped right in my downloads and cd'd to that directory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going off of the [Matplotlib install page](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html):

Which says "Click on the latest release of the “matplotlib” package, choose your python version (2.6, 2.7 or 3.2) and your platform (macosx or win32)."

I know that I've reverted to python 2.7 in order to use matplotlib on my Mac.

Comment: There is no package for 3.3 on OS X.  So far I've successfully installed it, but there are tons of errors when I run the tests.  I'm getting plots though.